# Verificar se há número em uma string

Tags: php

Preciso fazer varias validações em meu form, e uma delas é verificar se o nome digitado contem número em algum lugar da *string* seja no começo meio ou fim, eu ja tentei usar  `is_numeric` porem ele so funcionou  se só fosse números, e não uma mistura de numeros com letras.

O que eu poderia fazer?

Comment: Serve usar regex?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/901738/1244639, outra opção

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Filter_var com `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`

Uma maneira de verificar se a `string` contém pelo menos um número, sem utilizar expressão regular (que costuma ser mais lento), é usando a função `filter_var`.

Veja:

```
var_dump(filter_var('teste', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)); // ''

var_dump(filter_var('teste1', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)); // '1'
```

A flag `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` é responsável por remover todos os caracteres não numéricos da expressão e retornar somente os números. Assim podemos saber se tem números na `string` verificando se ela não retornou uma `string` vazia.

Exemplo:

```
filter_var($valor, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)) !== ''
```

Temos que **tomar cuidado**, pois o <s>bendito</s> do PHP compara `'0' == false` como sendo uma expressão `true`. Então foi por isso que usei a comparação `!  == ''`. Outro detalhe importante é que se você passar um `array` no primeiro parâmetro de `filter_var` (com `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`) ele vai retornar `false` ao invés de `''`.

Isso poderia causar uma "confusão de booleanos".

Então pensando no ponto de vista que eu passei acima, o mais inteligente a se fazer é :

## Combinando `FILTER_SANTIZE_NUMBER_INT` com `is_numeric`

Já que o que retornar de `FILTER_SANTIZE_NUMBER_INT` só vai retornar números, então podemos  usar a função `is_numeric` para saber se o resultado de `filter_var` é um número ou não, que está presente na *string*.

```
function contains_number($string) {
   return is_numeric(filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
}
```

Comment: `ctype_alnum('a');` retorna `true`?

Comment: Sim @jbueno. Por isso estou melhorando os detalhes.

Comment: Eu ia mesmo dizer que sua resposta está errada :p

Comment: Mas a outra resposta também não fala de alfanumérico. Fala só de números.

Comment: Como não? Ela não verifica se tem um número no meio da string?

Comment: @jbueno mas a outra resposta fala somente de números. Se eu passar só números, e não letras, será aceito. Mas isso também não foi o que o AP pediu, ele pediu só pra saber se tem número ou não. As duas respostas agora atendem

Comment: Agora sim @WallaceMaxters +1

Comment: Na minha opinião deveria remover a primeira parte da resposta com o ctype_alnum(), pois não resolve o problema. O uso do filter_var() resolve - apesar de não ter sido criada pra isso como as expressões regulares.

Comment: @NewtonWagner removido. Também concordo com você

Answer (score 8):

Estuda sobre [expressões regulares](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/) e da uma olhada no [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php)

```
if( preg_match('/\d+/', $nome)>0 ){
   echo 'Seu nome tem algum numero';
}
```

Essa regex vai detectar se tem um ou mais numeros em qualquer lugar da string.

Answer (score 4):

Segue abaixo algumas outras alternativas.

### [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php)

Você pode usar a função [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php) para filtrar somente números (e sinais de `+` e `-`) usando o filtro `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`, se a filtragem falhar, o resultado é `false`:

```
function encontrouNumeros($string) {
    return (filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) === '' ? false : true);
}

var_dump(encontrouNumeros("stack")); // bool(false)
var_dump(encontrouNumeros("st4ck")); // bool(true)
```

<sub>Para ponto flutuante use `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT`.</sub>

### [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ctype-digit.php)

Como [sugerido pelo Wallace Maxters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154142/verificar-se-h%C3%A1-numero-em-uma-string/154152?noredirect=1#comment318231_154152), também pode-se usar a função [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ctype-digit.php), é retornado `true` se todos os caracteres da *string* são numéricos, `false` caso contrário.

Para verificar se uma *string* contém números, verifique caractere por caractere num *loop*:

```
function encontrouNumeros2($string) {
    $indice = 0;
    while ($indice < strlen($string)) {
        if (ctype_digit($string[$indice]) === true) return true;
        $indice++;
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(encontrouNumeros2("stack")); // bool(false)
var_dump(encontrouNumeros2("st4ck")); // bool(true)
```

### [`strpbrk`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpbrk.php)

A função [`strpbrk`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpbrk.php) busca na *string* por um dos caracteres que estiverem num conjunto, retorna uma *string* iniciando do caractere encontrado, ou `false` se nenhum dos caracteres do conjunto for encontrado:

```
function encontrouNumeros3($string) {
    return strpbrk($string, '0123456789') !== false;
}

var_dump(encontrouNumeros3("stack")); // bool(false)
var_dump(encontrouNumeros3("st4ck")); // bool(true)
```

Comment: Eu também coloquei isso na resposta, mas só estou com medo de uma coisa: No php `'0' == false` também retorna `false`. E `'0'` é um número (estou abismado, mas vi isso aqui nos testes mesmo). Se você notar, eu botei `!== ''` para não dar problema.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Você está certo, vou ver isso.

Comment: Eu achei inteligente botar o `is_numeric` como resultado de `filter_var`. Talvez você queira uma sugestão para sua resposta: que tal usar `ctype_digit` no resultado do seu `filter_var`?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Já consertei o *bug*, agora retorna *true* se `filter_var` filtrar corretamente e falso se não. Você mencionou o `ctype_digit`, que me deu a ideia de usá-lo num *loop*, assim coloquei outra alternativa. :)

Comment: `! in_array(false, array_map('ctype_digit', str_split($value)))`

Comment: huehuehuehuehue

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta não especifica se deseja obter a posição do que encontrar como numérico, portanto, focando no trecho que diz que só precisa encontrar se há caracteres numéricos, faria algo assim.

```
function NumbersOnly($str, $float = false)
{
    $r = '';
    if ($float) {
        $r = '.';
        $str = str_replace(',', $r, $str);
    }
    return preg_replace('#[^0-9'.$r.']#', '', mb_convert_kana($str, 'n'));
}

$str = 'foo2';

if (!empty(NumbersOnly($str))) {
    echo 'Encontrou números';
} else {
    echo 'NÃO encontrou números';
}
```

## Cuidados com caracteres numéricos Zenkaku

A função `filter_var()` não considera os caracteres ZenKaku `１２３４５６７８９０` os quais são diferentes dos caracteres ASCII `1234567890`. Observe como visualmente o tamanho é diferente.

Se quiser algo mais consistente que detecte os caracteres Zenkaku, o exemplo acima é mais seguro.

Um teste com as 4 versões, incluindo as que foram postada nas outras respostas:

```
function phpfilter($str) {
    return filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}
function encontrouNumeros($string) {
    return (filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) === '' ? false : true);
}
function NumbersOnly($str, $float = false)
{
    $r = '';
    if ($float) {
        $r = '.';
        $str = str_replace(',', $r, $str);
    }
    return preg_replace('#[^0-9'.$r.']#', '', mb_convert_kana($str, 'n'));
}


$str = 'foo３'; // testando com zenkaku
//$str = 'foo'; // sem número
//$str = 'foo3'; // número ascii

if (!empty(phpfilter($str))) {
    echo 'Encontrou números';
} else {
    echo 'NÃO encontrou números';
}
echo '<br>';
if (encontrouNumeros($str)) {
    echo 'Encontrou números';
} else {
    echo 'NÃO encontrou números';
}
echo '<br>';
if (!empty(NumbersOnly($str))) {
    echo 'Encontrou números';
} else {
    echo 'NÃO encontrou números';
}

echo '<br>';
if( preg_match('/\d+/', $str)>0 ){
    echo 'Encontrou números';
} else {
    echo 'NÃO encontrou números';
}
```

## Alternativa com strpbrk()

Conforme postado em outra resposta, temos essa função serve muito bem com um código muito mais limpo:

```
function encontrouNumeros3($string) {
    return strpbrk($string, '0123456789') !== false;
}

var_dump(encontrouNumeros3("st４ack"));
```

Porém, novamente deve-se ter cuidado com os caracteres zenkaku. Para isso, bata adicioná-los na função.

```
function encontrouNumeros3($string) {
    return strpbrk($string, '0123456789１２３４５６７８９０') !== false;
}

var_dump(encontrouNumeros3("st４ack")); // retorna true
```

A diferença entre a função do primeiro exemplo `NumbersOnly()` e `strpbrk()` é que uma sanitiza e outra retorna booleano caso encontre qualquer um dos caracteres especificados no segundo parâmetro. Escolha o que for conveniente para o seu caso.

## Finalizando

Algo que pode ser o mais simples para o foco da pergunta:

```
if (preg_match('/\d+/', mb_convert_kana($str, 'n')) > 0) {
    echo 'Encontrou números';
} else {
    echo 'NÃO encontrou números';
}
```

Não fiz teste de performance. Mas a ideia é sanitizar com `mb_convert_kana()` e aplicar qualquer outra solução. Apenas veja qual é mais rápido.